# Error in Inserting values to Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a simple Database to add the values of product. While adding the entries in database I am getting an error in Logcat and the program get stop there and then.

I am not clear with the error but its something related to insertion of data or in query I have written. I tried all possible alternatives I could.

Program Code is :

**DataBase.java**

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, CreateTable.DB_NAME, null, CreateTable.DB_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String create = "Create Table " + CreateTable.TABLE_NAME + "( " + CreateTable.KEY_ID
                                        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + CreateTable.KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                                        + CreateTable.KEY_PRICE + " REAL)";

        db.execSQL(create);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    public void addProduct(Product p)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
        c.put(CreateTable.KEY_NAME, p.getName());
        c.put(CreateTable.KEY_PRICE, p.getPrice());

        db.insert(CreateTable.TABLE_NAME, null, c);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

**EnterDeatils.java**

```
public class EnterDeatils extends Activity {

    EditText name;
    EditText price;
    Button done;
    int id = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.enter_deatils);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtname);
        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtprice);
        done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndone);

        done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Product p = new Product();
                p.setId(id);
                p.setName(name.getText().toString());
                p.setPrice(Float.valueOf(price.getText().toString()));

                DataBase d = new DataBase(EnterDeatils.this);
                d.addProduct(p);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**LogCat Error:**

```
01-12 23:06:52.343: E/Database(382): Error inserting pPrice=12.0 pName=ds
01-12 23:06:52.343: E/Database(382): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Books has no column named pPrice: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Books(pPrice, pName) VALUES(?, ?);
```

Requesting you guys to just help me to identify the error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Uninstall the app so that any old version of the database file is removed.

Comment: How and application can be uninstalled from an emulator?

Comment: Use app manager in settings, or `adb uninstall <packagename>` on command line.

Comment: @laalto I guess that worked. Its not showing any error now. Could you please tell me exactly what cause this error?

Comment: Uninstall application have the same effect that onUpdate, both recreate database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` `onCreate()` is only called if the database file does not exist. If you modify the SQL in `onCreate()`, you'll have to ensure the database file is updated.

Two approaches:

- Delete the old version of the database. Uninstall is one way to do this. This way the database is created with whatever code you currently have in `onCreate()`. This is often the simplest way during app development.
- Bump up the database version number you pass to `SQLiteOpenHelper` superclass. If this number is different from the version number stored in the database file, `onUpgrade()` or `onDowngrade()` is called, and you can update the database schema. This is the preferred way when you already have released versions out so your users can preserve their data when updating your app.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your database from terminal

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/com.example.applicationname/databases
rm *
```

First you created table `Books` with `x` number of columns but `pPrice` column was not included in that create table query. Later on  you added this column name to your create table query. 
That's why this problem happened.

Try to delete the database. It will delete the old database from application and when you re start new database will be created.
`onCreate()` is only called if your database DOES NOT exist

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your database was created without column `KEY_PRICE`.
After that you have altered your code adding column `KEY_PRICE` to `String create`.

If this is true you must increment database version in order it be created again:

Change:

```
CreateTable.DB_VERSION = 1;
```

To

```
CreateTable.DB_VERSION = 2;
```

As laalto suggested change `onUpgrade`

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CreateTable.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

Comment: Won't help as `onUpgrade()` is not implemented.

Comment: @ramaral : I have created all the fields at a time. Not altered after creating.

Comment: Have you changed KEY_PRICE column name?

Comment: Probably I added a ",".

Answer (score -1):

Check if you are missing some space. I had same problem , and solved with adding space...