# Table * has no column named **

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to learn SQLite, trying basic things and (as expected) it doesn't really work.
I've tried to create another DB (different file), but the error remains the same. Please guide me. I an new to Android so I do not have much knowledge.

```
package net.multiplesystem.nosms.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class RegisterAdapter
{
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "register.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
    // SQL Statement to create a new database.
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"REGISTER"+
            "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "NAME text,"+"NUMBER text); ";
    // Variable to hold the database instanceSTER
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  RegisterAdapter(Context _context)
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public  RegisterAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
    {
        return db;
    }


    public void insertEntry(String userName,String number)
    {
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put("NUMBER",number);
        newValues.put("NAME", userName);


        // Insert the row into your table
        db.insert("REGISTER", null, newValues);
        ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
01-13 08:55:49.269: E/SQLiteLog(2588): (1) table REGISTER has no column named NAME
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588): Error inserting NAME=hhhh NUMBER=564
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table REGISTER has no column named NAME (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO REGISTER(NAME,NUMBER) VALUES (?,?)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
01-13 08:55:49.319: E/SQLiteDatabase(2588):     at net.multiplesystem.nosms.database.RegisterAdapter.insertEntry(RegisterAdapter.java:65)

package net.multiplesystem.nosms.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version)
    {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
    // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
    // to create a new one.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db)
    {
        _db.execSQL(RegisterAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
    // of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
    {
        // Log the version upgrade.
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
        // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
        // values.
        // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "REGISTER");
        // Create a new one.
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually execute DATABASE_CREATE somewhere?

Comment: yes in another activity.

Comment: Yesterday I had answered same question .. check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078184/error-in-inserting-values-to-database/21078592#21078592

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually create the table? It seems like the DATABASE_CREATE script is never executed.
If you have created it once and then changed the statement, make sure it is executed again by incrementing the database version.

DATABASE_VERSION=1, did you have a prior version without the NAME column? Try incrementing the DATABASE_VERSION (maybe add some logging/breakpoints) and see if the DB gets recreated.

Comment: please check the updated post i have included the other activity which execute DATABASE_CREATE script.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you migrated your table file before adding attributes.
I advice you to delete your database file
recreate an empty database file in the database folder then migrate.
and re-run your server this should work.